# Game Giveaway Round 3 - Diablo 3, Max Payne 3, and Ghost Recon: Future Soldier!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promotional-grant

**The deadline for applying to this game grant has now passed.**

The winners for this round are:

- Shinrai
- Fluttershy
- tiddy
- Mana
- James
- EBongo
- Mr. November
- Ullallulloo
- Axiom
- Ivo Flipse
- Stephen
- Arremer
- Kappei
- Mr Smooth
- Ampersand
- Decency
- ayckoster
- Brant
- cowgod
- Cort

Congratulations to our winners, and thanks to everyone who entered! We do game giveaways pretty frequently, so if you weren't selected this time, definitely check back.

Winners: if we need more information from you, you will be contacted shortly. Otherwise, your order will be placed asap.

If you selected Diablo 3, I will do my best to get orders placed today. Orders for Max Payne 3 and Ghost Recon will be placed shortly thereafter.

---

Welcome to Round 3 of the Gaming Promotional Grant! **This round’s featured games are Diablo 3 (standard edition), Max Payne 3, and Ghost Recon: Future Soldier**. Have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information about these three games!

**How it works:**

- Eligibility: All users with at least 300 reputation on gaming.stackexchange.com are eligible to receive one of these games for free.
- Requirements: All you have to do is ask 8 questions about your new game within the first 2 weeks of playing it. If you fulfill your commitment, you’ll be eligible for the next round (eligible, not *guaranteed*). If not, no worries - you just sit the next round out, but will still be eligible for future rounds.
- Up to 20 users will be selected at random to receive the game of their choice.
- Time frame: to allow us enough time to place orders before the games are released, applications will be accepted until Thursday May 10th at 11:59 pm UTC.

**To enter**, fill out [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHZxZzZVR242RG4ycVZocnR2TG1xOXc6MQ#gid=0), specifying which game you want and your prefered purchase method.

Please note: for this round, we are allowing reimbursements. If you have already pre-purchased one of these games, you may apply for the grant and be reimbursed. That means that for this round, if you happened to purchase a collector's edition, you can still get reimbursed for the cost of the standard edition.

However, for future grants, we will not be doing reimbursements; we will only be able to buy the game for you. We are able to purchase games from Amazon vendors that service countries besides the US (e.g. amazon.co.uk, amazon.de), so this should not raise concerns about regional lockout.

**Edit**:

- I've had several questions about how to fill out the form if you want a reimbursement. If you are getting a reimbursements, just indicate which game you purchased in the question "What game would you like?" and in the following question select "reimburse me."
- According to [Blizzard's Store FAQ](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/blizzard-store-faq#q13), you are able to gift digital downloads. However, upon calling and speaking to a customer service rep, we were told that this is a new feature and it is being rolled out gradually. It is unclear whether digital gifting will be available for Diablo 3.

  - Therefore: if you have already filled out the form requesting that we gift you a digital copy, you will be contacted individually if and when you are selected. If gifting is available, we will do that. Otherwise, we will arrange a same-day delivery through Amazon or you will have the option to purchase the game yourself and be reimbursed.
  - For those who have not yet filled out the form, you may still request that we gift you a digital copy, and we will do so if the option is available. If not, you will be contacted with the same options as above.

The deadline for applying for the game grant ends 5 days before the Diablo 3 release, so either way there will be plenty of time to figure this out.

Comment: Will those automatic entries from FFXIII-2/SCV/KOA/The Darkness II still count here if we didn't get ME3?

Comment: @Lauren Regarding future reimbursements, what about region-locking for console games? Of the current gen consoles, the Wii and 360 are *both* region-locked. Buying an NA version for an EU player won't work and vice versa. In addition, international shipping times will create an issue with being able to ask enough questions on release because of potential delays.

Comment: I ask not because I care that much but because I'm sure somebody else will ask so let's get it out of the way - I notice you're reinstating the explicit anybody-who-meets-their-commitment-gets-an-auto-in-for-the-next-round.  The last giveaway (ME3) didn't mention that - is it being applied retroactively to everybody who hit their quota last time?  (Also, I am also unable to access the doc at this time)

Comment: @Shinrai I'm not reinstating the automatic-in - just that if you fulfill your commitment  you will be eligible for the next round (as opposed to being ineligible if you don't fulfill your commitment). I'm sorry for the google form being inaccessible, some permission settings were wrong, but it should be working now.

Comment: @Lauren - Form is working now for me too.  As for the auto-in, that makes a lot more sense to me than the way you were doing it - you might consider mentioning this in the post, though, because it's worded very similarly to the way the previous one was and I'm sure somebody's bound to get the wrong idea.  (Their fault, but still)

Comment: @Shinrai good point, added a clarification.

Comment: @Lauren as far as I can tell from the Amazon shipping help page (http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_rel_topic?ie=UTF8&nodeId=596190) the only option for sending video games to Australia is priority courier shipping, which costs $25. Will this be acceptable? On the plus side it means that it would arrive in 3-5 days rather than the 18-32 days for standard shipping or 5-12 days for expedited shipping.

Comment: I noticed the form didn't ask me for my battle.net account. Is that correct or did I miss something?

Comment: How do Diablo digital purchases work? As far as I can tell you can't purchase it as a gift.

Comment: I put my name in the hat for Max Payne on PC/Steam last night and was checking release date this morning, and the PC version of the game is to be released 2 weeks after other platforms (1st June vs 18th May for EU), which makes it much harder for us to ask good questions as we'll be very late to the party (hell, I've found it painful enough being 3 days late because of US vs EU release gaps in the past). Nothing to do with you guys, of course, but annoying none the less. Oh, and I was wondering if PC players will get 2 weeks from the 2-weeks-late PC release date?

Comment: @DMA57361 you will have 2 weeks from the date you receive the game.  If you have a special circumstance such as the one you mentioned, just shoot me an email and let me know when you receive the game so I can make a note of it.

Comment: @jwaddell is there another Amazon vendor that services Australia?

Comment: @Lauren good to know, thanks. Guess I'll keep my fingers crossed for the draw and just see what I can come up with when the time comes... And this isn't special to me personally, looks like anyone else taking MP3 on PC will be similarly effected.

Comment: @Mr.November see my edit above.

Comment: @Mr.November, sure you can: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56430/is-there-a-way-to-gift-blizzard-games-using-battle-net

Comment: (oh, just read @Lauren's edit...)

Comment: @jwaddell amazon.com.au redirects to amazon.co.uk, which will ship standard to Australia for £8.48 (if I'm interpreting [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_492868_top_int?nodeId=11072981) correctly).

Comment: @Lauren Due to the fact that Diablo 3 had a wide closed beta, and a free open beta weekend, do questions made before release date count towards the minimum 8 requested?

Comment: @Drake - no, questions about the beta don't count towards the requirement. You must ask 8 questions within the first two weeks after receiving your game from us.

Comment: @jwaddell you can buy Diablo 3 through Amazon Global (http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=230659011) and from what I'm seeing (I'm trying to check it out to see if they'll ship here) we can get it through either expedited shipping or priority shipping. Dunno how much either costs though.

Comment: @MatthewRead according to http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_rel_topic?ie=UTF8&nodeId=524836 amazon.co.uk doesn't ship video games to Australia.

Comment: @MrSmooth I went to the Amazon Global site, then went to Shipping Rates & Policies->International->Australia, and video games only appears in the "Priority Courier" section.

Comment: @jwaddell It's also under the expedited shipping in the first row, lumped in with books etc. I can also confirm that if you try to check out with Diablo 3, it'll let you select either priority or expedited. Expedited seems to be around $16. Lauren will have to let us know if that's acceptable seeing as no other amazon site ships to Aus.

Comment: @jwaddell if that's the only option it's fine - as long as you've confirmed it will actually ship to you. Thanks for looking into it so carefully!

Comment: @jwaddell Boo, my bad.

Comment: When will the winners be announced?

Comment: Or, if they won't be announced, have they been notified?

Comment: I hope not, my mailbox is still empty. :D

Comment: @Shinrai see my edit to the post: Winners will be announced and contacted within the next couple of days. Sorry I can't do it right away, it takes a while to go through all the entries!

Comment: @Lauren - Oh, I was looking for an update at the end of the post, not the beginning. That answers the question!

Comment: So, where they noticed already? I will buy my own copy then, prices have already gone up since last week.

Comment: Congratulations to the winners!

Comment: I just wanted to thank @Lauren and all the other fine guys of Gaming S.E. This was totally unexpected, I was checking my mail and BAM! "You've received a gift copy of the game Max Payne 3". Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome @Kappei! Glad it was such a nice surprise :-)

Comment: @Lauren Those that chose reimbursement should go ahead and make our purchase, sending the scan of the receipt to gamegrant@stackoverflow.com as usual?

Comment: @Lauren Thanks a bunch! I replied in an e-mail with my mailing address, is there anything else I need to take care of?

Comment: @Decency nope you're good. Just got your email, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much :). I there any way I can check when the game will ship, I still have not received my D3 copy. Usually it takes only 1-2 days. I checked the availability on Amazon and it said 3 to 5 weeks :(.

Comment: @ayckoster shoot me an email with you order info and I'll check.